Different inventories, same group name
I want to run an Ansible playbook with more inventories and I know it can be done by specifying before each inventory -i command. But I have in two different inventories a group with the same name, but different hosts in the group. Is it possible to target all the machines from both inventories without modifying the inventories?
I couldn't try it because the machines are not available right now, I would like to know if it is possible

"I couldn't try it because the machines are not available right now", don't worry, just try. How? That's shown in the answer ...

Q: "I have in two different inventories a group with the same name, but different hosts in the group."
For example inventory files like
example.com.ini
[test]
one.example.com
two.example.com

and
example.net.ini
[test]
one.example.net
two.example.net

Q: "Is it possible to target all the machines from both inventories without modifying the inventories?"
Yes, of course, since a minimal example playbook example.ini.yml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - debug:

called via
ansible-playbook -i example.com.ini -i example.net.ini example.ini.yml

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ********************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [one.example.net] =>
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [two.example.net] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP **********************
one.example.com            : ok=1
one.example.net            : ok=1
two.example.com            : ok=1
two.example.net            : ok=1

